# Raid 1 or 5 for Colocation server with 5 wordpress sites, 1 CRM and 1 mail server?

Tags: web-server, vmware-esxi, centos6.4

I want to build colocation server with :

- 5 Wordpress sites with 50 view at a time (5*50 = 250)
- 1 CRM ASP.NET site with 50 view at a time
- 1 mailserver Kerio connect or MDaemon wiht 120 user

***My model :**

**- Server A - ESXi 5.1 - DELL™ PowerEdge™ R210-II with 16G RAM**

- Mysql1 on CentOS 6.4
- SQL1 on Win2k8
- IIS1 on Win2k8
- Apache1 on CentOS   6.4
- MDaemon1 on Win2k8

  **- Server B - ESXi 5.1 - DELL™ PowerEdge™ R210-II with 16G RAM**
- Mysql2 on CentOS 6.4 (cluster Mysql1)
- SQL2 on Win2k8 (cluster SQL1)
- IIS2 on Win2k8 (cluster IIS1)
- Apache2 on CentOS 6.4 (cluster Apache1)
- MDaemon2 on Win2k8 (backup for Mdaemon1)

Please advise me should use :

- 2 HDD SAS 15k with Raid 1 or
- 3 HDD SATA 10k with Raid 5 or
- Other?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Try 2 SATA SSD - cheaper than SAS 15k and a lot faster. Raid 1 - mirror. Finished. Beats the hell out of any other setup you try to have and has a lower price...